# How to list files which has certain tag in S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Here is my code:

```
import json, boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client("s3", region_name='us-east-1')
    response = client.list_objects(Bucket='test-bucket')
    return response
```

Above code is working fine for me. But I want to list all objects in the bucket which has a particular tag on the file(object), let's say

```
department:finance
```

I write below policy for it:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:List*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mynewbucket1122",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:ExistingObjectTag/department": "finance"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But I am getting errors, how can I get expected result.

Answer (score 1):

The bucket policy, even if it was correct, does not filter your objects by the tag. You still have to call your `list_objects`, get the full list of objects, and **iteratively**, inspect their tags to get only those that you are interested in.

In other words, you have to do the filtering in your code.

Comment: Thanks. Could u help me with this? How to filter files based on tags. I have not come through such features in code.

Comment: It would need to: (1) Call `list_objects()`, then (2) loop through each returned object and call [`get_object_tagging()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object_tagging) to obtain the tags on that object. Your code can then examine the `TagSet` returned. You would _not_ write an IAM Policy just to filter results from an API call.